# Открыть доступ к апачу из интернета

Tags: windows, apache, сервер

Брандмауэр отключил, порт вроде разрешил, а не пингуется!

Comment: как открывали порт? каким образом получаете доступ в интернет? где связь между Апач и Пинг?

Answer (score 2):

80-й порт нужно не пингом проверять, а делать на него telnet.И поглядеть через netstat -na | find "LISTEN", открыт ли он вообще на прослушку